# Jquery Calling lightbox from updated div not working

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I'm working in a website were we update the content of a div using Jquery.

Inside the content we use to update the div there are some buttons with jquery actions attached.

The first time the document is loaded lightbox is OK, but after the div content is updated the jquery lightbox doesnt works.

Any comments welcome ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[activate lightbox on dynamically added content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597511/activate-lightbox-on-dynamically-added-content)

Is that what you're looking for?