# wordpress jQuery Lightbox not working on front page

Tags: jquery, wordpress, lightbox

I wrote a read more function for my front page that loads in a section of html from another file.

When this section drops down the gallery enclosed within this section doesn't work.  However, if you go to the single page article it works.

I know it is something to do with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597511/activate-lightbox-on-dynamically-added-content).

I'm using [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jquery-lightbox-balupton-edition/) but I'm unsure of how to fix it.

Does anyone know what I can do?

thanks.

---

I tried that and added the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").live('click',function(e){                
        alert("clicked");
        $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
    });
});
```

When the image is clicked, the alert pops up but the browser still diverts you to the link.

Any ideas?

Comment: Post the site URL so people can look at the code.

Comment: Use `e.preventDefault();` inside the live function.

Answer (score 0):

Trying using prettyPhoto lightbox, I've had a lot of success using it with WordPress.

http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/